# How do I customize bootstrap in a meteor application?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

Meteor is great, and supports bootstrap using a 'smart package' that can be included like this:

```
meteor add bootstrap
```

and then the css, javascript, and images are magically included at runtime in the browser. That's great, but I'd like to customize bootstrap to not look like every other bootstrap site on the net. Ordinarily I'd use the [bootstrap customize](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html) functionality, but that's not available here. What's the best way for me to apply customizations to bootstrap in a meteor context?

It would be particularly ideal if I could generate a LESS file from the Bootstrap customizer, plop it into my directory, and have done with it. It turns out that Bootswatch generated CSS messes up fluid layouts, and besides, any third party is going to be out of date sooner rather than later.

Comment: There is a less smart package these days, maybe it would be useful in your setup?

Answer (score 7):

Well, it seems that the solution is just as simple as it coule be. I was able to override the defaults by simply including a css file in the root of my meteor app. I happened to use a canned css file from [Bootswatch](http://bootswatch.com/), but I presume one could roll this up by hand as well.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up removing the meteor bootstrap package altogether and install it as a `git submodule` within `packages`.

I made my own custom packaged git repo [meteor-bootstrap](https://github.com/littke/meteor-bootstrap/tree/meteor-packaged) to which I also added a `package.js` file with instructions on which files I want to use. (See the branch `meteor-packaged`).

I did this to be able to change Bootstrap variables and use the LESS mixins freely, and not to include every single Bootstrap JS-file.

Comment: So I've added it into the packages folder, but dont you need to load the files into the client or public folders to get them to compile. Are you just referencing the files as includes from the package folder? I'm going to try that.

Answer (score 0):

I created a shell script to generate a custom bootstrap Meteor package from either a precompiled distribution, or your own clone of the Bootstrap Git repository.

You can find it here, along with usage information:
https://github.com/wojas/meteor-package-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

This link provides a good and smarter way to use bootstrap with Meteor.
The customization is done through variables and also through mixins. U can try it if u want.

---

> https://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteorjs-and-twitter-bootstrap-the-right-way